# XGBoost4J-Spark Training Performance with vector Assembler and custom dense vector results in two completely different trained model file

Tags: apache-spark-mllib, xgboost

I am currently working with XGBoost4j. To use it I have to transform my training data using Vector Assembler. Following are my problem:

1. I transform my data using vector Assembler. Output of vector Assembler is feature Vector Column.
   **When does Vector assembler give output columns as dense vectorand when it get converted to sparse vector ?** **How should I set my missing value for Vector assembler to Non-zero value**.
2. To avoid above, I also tried to use following code to transform my training data:

```
val feature_col = array(testing.drop("cust_xref_id","dep_var").columns.map(col).map(_.cast(DoubleType)): _*)

val trainDF = train.select(train("dep_var").cast(DoubleType), train("cust_xref_id").cast(StringType) ,feature_col).map(r => (r.getAs[Double](0), r.getAs[Long](1),**org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vectors.dense(r.getAs[mutable.WrappedArray[Double]**](2).toArray))).toDF("label","key","features")

where, Key_column is cust_xref_id and my label column is dep_var.
```

But, **this result in drastic model performance drop**. I am not sure what might be the Issue

2. If I have a model where "0" is a meaningful value. How to should I prevent it to be treated as missing value in XGBoost4j Training.

https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/release_0.90/jvm/xgboost4j_spark_tutorial.html

In the above mention link, they have ask us to replace 0 to any other value. I have some feature out of one hot encoding, how should I handle that ?

I am using versions 0.82 and 0.9.

Please help me resolve this Issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm (very!) late to the party but the answer is in the following thread:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/61847377/5726057

where you can find both an explanation to your question (see Naveed's last comment) and the Scala code to solve it by creating a new MLlib Transformer that you can include in your pipelines.